# UWP ContentDialog Disable PrimaryButton

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a ContentDialog, that links it's

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="ParadigmaN.Apps.Common.Controls.EditPersonContentDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ParadigmaN.Apps.Common.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Uid="EditorPersonas"
    Title=""
    PrimaryButtonText="Aceptar"
    SecondaryButtonText="Cancelar"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
    PrimaryButtonCommand="{Binding ElementName=CtrPerson,Path=DataContext.GuardarCommand}">
    <Grid>
        <local:PersonControl x:Name="CtrPerson"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

But PrimaryButton remains enabled even my CanExecuteCommand returns false.

How Can I control, enabled status of PrimaryButton  from a ContentDialog?

Comment: It is seriously disturbing that this command on that button doesn't behave as any other. I consider it a bug and would like to report it but can't find where to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property named **IsPrimaryButtonEnabled** you can use that property to enable or disable PrimaryButton of a ContentDialog.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.isprimarybuttonenabled